# Как правильно сформировать таблицу в templates Django

Tags: django, django-orm, django-model, django-template

Помоги, пожалуйста, разобраться как правильно сделать:

> Bank/models.py

```
class Bank(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Название Банка')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Банк'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Банки'


class BankAccount(models.Model):
    company = models.ForeignKey('Company.Company', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Фирма',
                                related_name='company')
    bank = models.ForeignKey('Bank', null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Банк', related_name='bank')
    login_bank = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Логин', null=False)
    password_bank = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Пароль', null=False)

    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    balance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=15, decimal_places=2, blank=True, null=True)
```

> Company/models.py

```
class Company(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Название фирмы')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=100, verbose_name='Название на латинице',blank=True)
    inn = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='ИНН')
    okved = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='ОКВЭД')
    legal_address = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Юр.Адресс')
    legal_city = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Юр.Город')
    date_of_application = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Дата подачи')
    registration_date = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Дата регистрации')
    charter_number = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name='Номер устава')
    email = models.EmailField(blank=True)
    directors = models.ForeignKey(Director, null=True, verbose_name='Директор', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    bankaccount = models.ForeignKey('bank.BankAccount', null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='Банк',
                                    on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='bankaccount')
```

> Bank/views.py

```
class BankViews(ListView):
    model = BankAccount
    template_name = 'bank/bank.html'
 
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['company'] = Company.objects.all()
        context['bankAccounts'] = BankAccount.objects.select_related('company', 'bank').order_by('bank_id')
        context['balance'] = BankAccount.objects.aggregate(balance=Sum('balance', decimal_places=2))
        return context
 
    def get_queryset(self):
        return BankAccount.objects.values('bank__name', 'bank__id').order_by('bank_id').annotate(
            total=Sum('balance'), date_updated=Min('date_updated'))
```

> Bank/templates/bank.html

```
{% extends "home.html" %}
{% block title %} Банки {% endblock title %}
{% block header %} Список Банков {% endblock header %}
{% load filter %}

{% block content %}
<form action="{% url 'bank:bank' %}" method="GET">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Общий баланс :{{balance.balance|floatformat:'-2'}} рублей">
</form>
<div class="col-md-12 my-2">
    <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
            <td>   </td>
            {% for com in company%}
                <td>{{com}}</td>
            {% endfor%}
        </tr>
 
         <tr>
            {% for object in object_list %}
                <td><a class="nav-link" href="#">{{object.bank__name}}</a></td>
                    {% for i in bankAccounts %}
                            {% if i.bank_id == object.bank__id %}
                                <td>{{i}}</td>
                            {% endif%}
                    {% endfor%}
         </tr>
            {% endfor %}
    </table>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

На выходе хочу получить таблицу, сверху список фирм (столбцы), строки (Банки).
Вот со строками сложности не составило,но со столбцами возникли трудности скрин прилагаю.
Я может быть что-то упускаю?
[image: Скрин результата]

P.S. То есть в первом столбце должно отобразить Pакета | Открытие, ниже Ракета | Альфа-банк, и так далее. Буду очень благодарен за любую помошь или подсказку.

Answer (score 1):

Вы всегда можете сделать двумерный массив, преставляющий ващу таблицу в коде, или генератор.

И не нужно ничего вычислять в шаблоне, шаблон должен только выводить данные и, а не рассчитывать их расположение в ячейках. Конечно, рендер таблицы подходит под описание [из документации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/templates/), но у вас нет достаточного функционала и возможностей, чтобы просто это реализовать. Так что предлагаю подготовить необходимые данные перед передачей в рендер.